# ¿Cómo ordenar los menús y submenús correspondientes en Java + PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, primefaces

El problema ocurre generando los menús correspondientes. Debería mostrar: Inicio, Compras, Ventas... pero en su lugar lo que se muestra es: Ventas, Ventas, Ventas...

En esta imagen se puede ver la multiplicidad de los menús Ventas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código correspondiente es:

```
public void establecerPermisos(){

    for(SubMenu m:lista){

        if(m.getMenu().getTipo().equals("S")){
            DefaultSubMenu firstSubMenu=new DefaultSubMenu(m.getMenu().getNomMenu());
            for(SubMenu i:lista){
                Menu menu=i.getMenu();
                 if(menu!=null){
                     if(menu.getIdMenu()==m.getIdsubmenu()){
                         DefaultMenuItem item=new DefaultMenuItem(i.getNombresubmenu());
                         firstSubMenu.addElement(item);
                     }
                 }
            }
           model.addElement(firstSubMenu);
        }else{
             if(m.getIdsubmenu()==0){
                 DefaultMenuItem item=new DefaultMenuItem(m.getNombresubmenu());
                 model.addElement(item);
             }
        }
    }
}

public List<SubMenu> listar() throws Exception{      
    List<SubMenu> lista;
    ResultSet rs;
    Menu menu=new Menu();        
    SubMenu submenu=new SubMenu();        
    EmpleadoDao dao=new EmpleadoDao();
    dao.listar();               
    try{            
        this.Conectar();      
        PreparedStatement st=this.getCn().prepareCall("select
                                           m.idMenu,m.codMenu,m.nomMenu,
                                           m.link,m.tipo,m.estadoMenu,
                                           s.idSubMenu,s.itemSubMenu,
                                           s.nombreSubMenu,s.linkSubMenu,
                                           s.estadoSubMenu,s.tipo,
                                           s.idMenu from menu m \n" +
       "inner join submenu s on m.idmenu=s.idmenu group by m.nomMenu");       

        rs=st.executeQuery();
        lista=new ArrayList();

        while(rs.next()){                            
            menu.setIdMenu(rs.getInt("m.idMenu"));             
            menu.setCodMenu(rs.getString("m.codMenu"));    
            menu.setNomMenu(rs.getString("nomMenu"));
            menu.setLink(rs.getString("m.link"));
            menu.setTipo(rs.getString("m.tipo"));
            menu.setEstadomenu(rs.getString("m.estadoMenu"));
            submenu.setIdsubmenu(rs.getInt("s.idSubMenu"));
            submenu.setItemsubmenu(rs.getString("s.itemSubMenu"));
            submenu.setNombresubmenu(rs.getString("s.nombreSubMenu"));
            submenu.setLinksubmenu(rs.getString("s.linkSubMenu"));
            submenu.setEstadosubmenu(rs.getString("s.estadoSubMenu"));
            submenu.setTipo(rs.getString("s.tipo"));
            menu.setIdMenu(rs.getInt("s.idMenu"));
            submenu.setMenu(menu);
            lista.add(submenu);  
            //lista3.add(menu);
        }            
    }catch(Exception e){            
        throw e;
    }finally{            
        this.Cerrar();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ciertamente la forma en como tienes los datos tiene razón en lo que te pasa.
Actualmente tu algoritmo de creación de menúes recorre la propia lista por cada iteración.
El problema es que al recorrer repetidamente tu lista, pues obviamente vas duplicando instancias y eso provoca que tu menú tenga el aspecto que tiene.

La idea es la siguiente:

1. En el primer `for` debes indicar cual es el registro actual (con su idMenu)
2. En el `for` interno, deberás procesar únicamente los que coincidan con ese id actual (ahora mismo los procesas todos), es decir `if (actual == i.getmenu().getIdMenu())`
3. Luego de que ubicas todos los submenus para un menú, marcarlos de alguna manera para que en la siguiente iteración no sean tomados en cuenta y por ende no te duplique el componente de tu menu.

Tu inconveniente es identificar quién ya fue procesado para que no se vuelva a procesar. Te propongo lo siguiente:

En tus clases `SubMenu` y `Menu` crea un atributo `boolean procesado` (con sus `getter` y `setter`), al atributo procesado del `SubMenu` le darás valor `true` dentro del `for` interno y al atributo procesado de `Menu` le darás valor `true` al salir del `for` interno.

Para cada iteración del `for` principal solo entrarás a procesar el registro si éste tiene el atributo `procesado` con valor `false`. Modifica tu método `establecerPermisos()` así:

```
//Marco con /**/ las líneas que debes agregar

public void establecerPermisos() {
    for(SubMenu m : lista) {

/**/    if(!m.isProcessed()) { //colocar este atributo en el Bean SubMenu
/**/    int actual = m.getMenu().getIdMenu();

        if(m.getMenu().getTipo().equals("S")) {
            DefaultSubMenu firstSubMenu=new DefaultSubMenu(m.getMenu().getNomMenu());

            for(SubMenu i:lista) {
/**/            if(actual == i.getMenu().getIdMenu() && !i.isProcessed()) {
                    Menu menu= i.getMenu();

                    if(menu!=null) {
                        if(menu.getIdMenu()==m.getIdsubmenu()) {
                            DefaultMenuItem item=new DefaultMenuItem(i.getNombresubmenu());
                            firstSubMenu.addElement(item);
/**/                i.setProcessed(true);
                        }
                    }
/**/            }
            }
            model.addElement(firstSubMenu);
/**/        m.getMenu().setProcessed(true); //colocar este atributo en el Bean Menu
        } else {
             if(m.getIdsubmenu() == 0) {
                 DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(m.getNombresubmenu());
                 model.addElement(item);
             }
        }       
/**/ }
    }
}
```

Prueba este enfoque para tu procesamiento y nos comentas.
Saludos,

Comment: ok voy a probarlo pero tambien encontre una solucion pero la solucion esta enfocado a una sola tabla que es menu se de antemanno que es una tabla recursiva muchas gracias  Rosendo

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta después de realizar debug. Había que inicializar el menú y submenú en cada iteración del bucle `while`:

```
while(rs.next()){  

    Menu menu = new Menu();
    SubMenu submenu = new SubMenu();

    menu.setIdMenu(rs.getInt("m.idMenu"));             
    menu.setCodMenu(rs.getString("m.codMenu"));    
    menu.setNomMenu(rs.getString("nomMenu"));
    menu.setLink(rs.getString("m.link"));
    menu.setTipo(rs.getString("m.tipo"));
    menu.setEstadomenu(rs.getString("m.estadoMenu"));
    submenu.setIdsubmenu(rs.getInt("s.idSubMenu"));
    submenu.setItemsubmenu(rs.getString("s.itemSubMenu"));
    submenu.setNombresubmenu(rs.getString("s.nombreSubMenu"));
    submenu.setLinksubmenu(rs.getString("s.linkSubMenu"));
    submenu.setEstadosubmenu(rs.getString("s.estadoSubMenu"));
    submenu.setTipo(rs.getString("s.tipo"));
    menu.setIdMenu(rs.getInt("s.idMenu"));
    submenu.setMenu(menu);
    lista.add(submenu);  
    //lista3.add(menu);
}
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar se duplica los menu con sus correspondientes submenu alguien de ustedes si me puede dar ideas en la solución muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tal, solo para ir descartando cosas; la consulta a la base de datos, ¿extrae la información de forma correcta (sin duplicados)?

Comment: extrae de forma correcta

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar una imagen o texto del resultado de tu consulta a la base de datos en tu pregunta ?

Comment: Lo interesante es que los items Inicio, Compras y Ventas, no están duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno espero que alguien me apoye

bueno a mi parecer el problema esta

for( SubMenu m:lista){

```
         if(m.getMenu().getTipo().equals("S")){          
            DefaultSubMenu firstSubMenu=new DefaultSubMenu(m.getMenu().getNomMenu());
```

voy añadir un if para que me controle los menus repetidos pero no se como podre controlarlo. he realizado comparaciones con el codigodesubmenu vs codmenu pero  no funciona. como hago para comparar los codigo de menu y si se repite que muestre una sola vez.

espero que alguien me apoye con otro planteamiento. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Dejo la imagen de la consulta la base de datos esta en MYSQL notara que son dos tablas relacionadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]